# C++ Compilation error with function of same name

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation

Consider a scenario where I have declared 2 functions with same name, at which step would the compiler know that the function has same name? Preprocessing/Compilation/Linking. As far as I know the compiler will link the functions in the linker step and find the ambiguous function.

Comment: Compilation phase. You can see the preprocessor by giving -E tag to g++.

Comment: Possibly breaking the One Definition Rule - no diagnostic required: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether you've declared those two functions in the same file or not.

If the functions are declared in the same file - compilation phase.

If the functions are declared in two separate files which need to be linked for your program to work - linking phase.